# Arduino - How to show a table when you push a button?

Tags: button, arduino, arduino-uno

I want to show a table with certain values when I push a button in arduino-uno.
I have different buttons that are use to read a password, but I need the   `pinMode(8, INPUT);` to show the records.

**This code to show the table** when I was using the keyboard on the monitor, but I need to change this to use the `pinMode(8, INPUT);` instead the button 0 of the keyboard.

```cpp
  if (Serial.available()>0) {
    incomingByte = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
    Serial.println(incomingByte);
    int num=incomingByte.toInt();
    if (incomingByte=="0"){
      for (int x=0; x<tam;x++){ 
      }
}
```

**Here is more code:**

```cpp
//Pushbutton
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(2,INPUT);  //button 1
  pinMode(3,INPUT); //button 2
  pinMode(4,INPUT); //button 3
  pinMode(5,INPUT); //button 4
  pinMode(6, OUTPUT); //LED RED
  pinMode(7, OUTPUT); //LED GREEN
  pinMode(8, INPUT); //button to show the tabl
  pinMode(11, OUTPUT); //buzzer
}
void loop()
{
  pushButton(2,1,0);
  pushButton(3,2,1);
  pushButton(4,3,2);
  pushButton(5,4,3);

  if (Serial.available()>0) {
    incomingByte = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
    Serial.println(incomingByte);
    int num=incomingByte.toInt();
    if (incomingByte=="0"){
      for (int x=0; x<tam;x++){ 
      }
}

//Funcion pushButton
String pushButton(int pin, int valor, int index)
{
  int buttonState=digitalRead(pin);
  int state;
  String valor_s=String(valor);
  state=stateS[index];

  switch(state)
  {
    case 0:
      if (buttonState==1){
        state=1;
        num=num+valor_s;
        if (num.length()==4){
          Serial.println(num);
          for (int i = 0; i < 10; i = i + 1) {
            if (client[i]==num){
              count[i]=count[i]+1;
              found=true;
              x=i;
              Serial.println("found"); 
              break;
            } 
          } //fin for
       //* more code *//
        }
      } //case 0     
      break;

    case 1:
      if (buttonState==0){
        state=0;
      }
      break;   
  } //switch
     stateS[index]=state;
     return num;
} //Fin String pushButton
```

Comment: Looking at the rest of your code, you seem to know how to read a button and how to set up an if statement to only do something when the button is pressed.  All you have to do is set that up and put the lines to print out your table inside of it.  I'm not seeing what's complicated here.